# class template argument deduction for template alias of an alias (C++20)

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++20

I am using `boost::outcome_v2::result` with a custom type for the error and an alias to this type.

Now I am struggling to get class template argument deduction to work for my alias.

The code:

```
class my_error{ ... };

template <typename result_t>
using my_result = boost::outcome_v2::result<result_t, my_error>;
```

The issue is that when I return this type from a function I can't use class template argument deduction for the result type:

```
const my_result res = some_function();
```

But it works if I use `boost::outcome_v2::result` directly:

```
const boost::outcome_v2::result res = some_function();
```

Is there a way to write a deduction guide for my alias so that it can work as well?

[Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/dz7zY6Wrn)

Comment: Why not just `auto const res=/*...*/`?

Comment: @Red.Wave That is what I have at the moment. The 'problem' I have with `auto` is if the interface changes I want to fail at the assignment point, not later down in the code with where `res.has_value()` is called (or something else), `auto` hides the failure point. I also prefer explicit types over auto

Comment: I don't like adhoc tricks. But you can define a `concept` for your template and `static_assert` on `decltype`. I am not sure if a local(none argument) object can use shorthand template constraints, but if it can I'd use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to write a deduction guide for my alias so that it can work as well?

No, as alias templates are just an alias for a type, it is by design not allowed to write explicit deduction guide *specifically* for an alias template.

Rather, this is an inherent and known limitation of CTAD, as highlighted in [P1021R6](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1021r6.html) (*[Core] Filling holes in Class Template Argument Deduction*)

> #### Class Template Argument Deduction for alias templates
>
> While Class Template Argument Deduction makes type inferencing easier when constructing classes, it doesn't work for type aliases, penalizing the use of type aliases and creating unnecessary inconsistency.
>
> [...]
>
> Finally, in the spirit of alias templates being simply an alias for the type, we do not propose allowing the programmer to write explicit deduction guides specifically for an alias template.

[P1814R0](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1814r0.html) (*Wording for Class Template Argument Deduction for Alias Templates*) broke out the alias template parts of P1021, and was [accepted by CWG in 2019](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/566), but [Clang has not yet implemented it](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) and [GCC doesn't even list its status towards the paper](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html).

Note however that in your case, `result` [is also an alias template](https://github.com/boostorg/outcome/blob/master/include/boost/outcome/result.hpp#L41), so you are actually not comparing CTAD for alias templates vs a non-alias template. [Clang, for example](https://godbolt.org/z/r8GoxvEvP), rejects both cases.